# Tags Displaying in the wrong order in XML development in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Goal: Producing an xml file from an Excel sheet:

I am trying to display:

```
   <SchufaService version="2.0"  
   xmlns="http://www.schufa.de/siml/2.0/final">
```

I am currently getting:

```
   <SchufaService  
   xmlns="http://www.schufa.de/siml/2.0/final" version="2.0">
```

I am using this Ruby code:

```
   xml.SchufaService("version": "2.0","xmlns":
   "https://www.schufa.de/siml/2.0/final") do
```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Please provide proper code snippet and mention library/tool you are using to build xml.

Also please read about how to format code on stackoverflow. It will allow more people to understand and respond to your issues. 

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I have edited code as required.

Comment: You should either use string keys with hashrockets `xml.SchufaService("version" => "2.0","xmlns" =>
   "https://www.schufa.de/siml/2.0/final")` or symbol keys `xml.SchufaService(version: "2.0", xmlns:
   "https://www.schufa.de/siml/2.0/final")`. Using strings with the new hash syntax coerces the keys into symbols and is regarded as bad style as it will not give the expected hash. This does not effect the ordering through which is inconsequential.

Comment: For example if you do `{ "foo": "bar" }["foo"]` it will return nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have shown in your question is a single tag (called "element" in XML) with two attributes. In XML, the order of attributes in a tag is not significant, nor is whitespace. Thus, the two tags you have posted are semantically exactly the same.

This is defined in the [XML specification, Section 3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags):

> Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.

Any XML parser reading the output produced by your code will see exactly the same result as your "target" output.